# Java: FE vs BE - How To Streamline The Process?

Tags: java, jsp, frontend

I am developing a web facing application in Java.  My frontend developers are finding the compilation cycle to be inconvenient because its time consuming. Does anyone know common strategies for streamlining the development process for web site creation in a Java setting?

Comment: JSPs are recompiled by the container. You'll only need to recompile if your java classes change.

Comment: Its an uberjar, no container, plus its using the apache velocity template.

Comment: I'm confused. How can you run JSP without container support? Something should translate it to a servlet and compile it.

Comment: Not JSP, no container, its an embedded Jetty uberjar using Apache velocity.  The frontend devs feel the compilation cycle is cumbersome.